# Class with generic parameter of the same generic class type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I had a class which represents a prefix search tree:

```
public class PrefixTree<TData>
{
    private PrefixTree<TData>[] _children;

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        _children = new PrefixTree<TData>[10];
    }
}
```

Then I created a derived class with additional features for its nodes:

```
public class NewPrefixTree<TData> : PrefixTree<TData>
```

The problem is that in `SomeMethod()` of derived class we still create instances of base class and it doesn't fit the meaning.

I refactored the base class to this:

```
public abstract class PrefixTree<TData, TNode>
    where TNode : PrefixTree<TData, TNode>, new()
{
    private TNode[] _children;

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        _children = new TNode[10];
    } 
}
```

Despite the base class has complete functionality itself, I had to make it `abstract` because I can't write `new DigitalPrefixTree<`*`TData`*`, DigitalPrefixTree<int,` **`...`**`>>()` .

But now I can use it this way and it works perfectly:

```
public class NewPrefixTree<TData> : PrefixTree<TData, NewPrefixTree<TData>> {} // for derived class
//or
public class PrefixTree<TData> : PrefixTree<TData, PrefixTree<TData>> {} // to use the base functionality
```

I've never done this before and I wonder if it's a good idea to declare a class with generic parameter of the same generic class type. Or I need to make some tricks with co/contra-variance of generic interfaces (but it probably doesn't work as I use the class type as method’s parameters type and as return type as well)?

Comment: When it comes to trees, the best is to not use generics.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public interface INode<out TData>
{
    TData Data { get; }

    IEnumerable<INode<TData>> Children { get; }

    public IEnumerable<TRequiredData> GetNestedData<TRequiredData>();
}

public interface ITree<out TData>
{
    IEnumerable<INode<TData>> Children { get; }

    IEnumerable<TRequiredData> GetNestedData<TRequiredData>();
}

public class Node<TData> : INode<TData>
{
    public TData Data { get; }
    public IEnumerable<INode<TData>> Children { get; }

    public Node(TData data, IEnumerable<INode<TData>>? children = null)
    {
        Data = data;
        Children = children ?? Enumerable.Empty<INode<TData>>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TRequiredData> GetNestedData<TRequiredData>()
    {
        List<TRequiredData> result = new();

        if (Data is TRequiredData requiredData)
            result.Add(requiredData);

        foreach (var child in Children)
            result.AddRange(child.GetNestedData<TRequiredData>());

        return result;
    }
}

public class Tree<TData> : ITree<TData>
{
    public IEnumerable<INode<TData>> Children { get; }

    public Tree(IEnumerable<INode<TData>> children)
    {
        Children = children;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TRequiredData> GetNestedData<TRequiredData>()
    {
        List<TRequiredData> result = new();

        foreach (var node in Children)
            result.AddRange(node.GetNestedData<TRequiredData>());

        return result;
    }
}
```

And here is example of usage:

```
    record SomeRecord();

    class SomeClass {}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var nodeWithNested = new Node<SomeClass>(
            data: new SomeClass(),
            children: new List<INode<SomeClass>>()
            {
                new Node<SomeClass>(new SomeClass()),
                new Node<SomeClass>(new SomeClass())
            });

        var nodes = new List<INode<object>>()
        {
            new Node<SomeClass>(new SomeClass()),
            nodeWithNested,
            new Node<SomeRecord>(new SomeRecord()),
        };

        var tree = new Tree<object>(nodes);

        var someClasses = tree.GetNestedData<SomeClass>(); // 4 items
        var someRecords = tree.GetNestedData<SomeRecord>(); // 1 item
    }
```

This approach based on [out generic modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier).

The only restriction is that you can not use structs (int, bool and ect.) as they don't have common object to cast to.

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alexander!
Using covariant interface is a good decision for common trees. But for my case of prefix search tree (called also ['trie'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)) it is not very suitable:
1. The point is that the tree class (and only the tree class due to algorithm integrity) is responsible for creating node children.
2. In addition and as a consequence of p.1, we have base methods like `Add(TData data, string prefix)` which can't be declared in covariant interface (with `out` generic modifier).

Comment: Maybe [this repository](https://github.com/gmamaladze/trienet) will be useful for you.